# Sync Two Textbox Lines VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

How do I sync 2 Textboxes? I mean, if I randomize the first Textbox (Randomize Text Lines) how do the 2nd Textbox be synchronized after the first Textbox?

[image: IMG1]
[image: IMG2]

I also want the 4 Textboxes containing the items to be saved in (Answer.dat) for example if in the first Textbox I have the element (BlackJack) in the 2nd Textbox element (21) in the 3rd Textbox the Poker element and the fourth Textbox element Bingo.

I want to save this in the new line (in my text file) to be something like the model (Blank Empty + Word(Textbox3) + Space + Word(Textbox4) + Space + Word(Textbox5) + Space + Word(Textbox6) this is the Screenshot how the items want to be saved. Unfortunately, I'm not doing too well with the blank at first.

[image: IMG3]

[image: IMG4]

```
 Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        TextBox1.Text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath + ("\Data\Question.dat"))
        TextBox2.Text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath + ("\Data\Answer.dat"))
    End Sub
End Class
```

So how can I do to save in a new line of Textbox (Save to my text file) the question and the answers in the textbox? following the example given?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below will keep the rows synchronized on a random shuffle.  If you don't want repeated rows, you will have to code validation to throw-out draws that have already occurred.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim text1 As String
        Dim text2 As String
        Dim textarray1 As New ArrayList
        Dim textarray2 As New ArrayList
        Dim NextMember As String = ""
        Dim Rand As New Random
        Dim RandNum As Integer = 0
        TextBox1.Clear()
        TextBox2.Clear()


        text1 = "one" & vbCrLf & "two" & vbCrLf & "three" & vbCrLf
        text2 = "A" & vbCrLf & "B" & vbCrLf & "C" & vbCrLf

        For i = 1 To Len(text1)
            Do Until Mid(text1, i, 1) = vbCr
                NextMember = NextMember & Mid(text1, i, 1)
                i = i + 1
            Loop

            textarray1.Add(NextMember)
            i = i + 1
            NextMember = ""
        Next

        For i = 1 To Len(text2)
            Do Until Mid(text2, i, 1) = vbCr
                NextMember = NextMember & Mid(text2, i, 1)
                i = i + 1
            Loop

            textarray2.Add(NextMember)
            i = i + 1
            NextMember = ""
        Next


        For i = 0 To textarray1.Count - 1
            RandNum = Rand.Next(textarray1.Count)
            TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & textarray1(RandNum) & vbCrLf
            TextBox2.Text = TextBox2.Text & textarray2(RandNum) & vbCrLf
        Next



    End Sub
```